# Spark 3.3.0 performance issue comparing to 3.1.1

Tags: performance, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm upgrading my Spark version from 3.1.1 to 3.3.0 (actually Glue 3.0 to Glue 4.0) and facing with performance issue. I can see in spark UI logs that there is extra shuffle appears. Also, I can see that in 3.1.1 version there are a lot of ReusedExchange, however, in 3.3.0 there are no ReusedExcange's. Tests have been done on same dataset and same transformations.

Any advices how to manage this?

Also, I tried with both

```
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled = false / true,
```

result is the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since Spark 3.2 it has optimization options enabled by default in my case setting spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst to false resolved performance issue.

More details at https://dev.to/aplotnikov/spark-tip-disable-adaptive-query-execution-aqe-for-compute-intensive-tasks-5bl0